# How To Distinguish The Extra bits In Huffman Decoding

Tags: bit, decoding, huffman-code

I'm trying to decode a file using Huffman. Suppose I got the characters AAAAABBBC and Suppose the codes for distinct characters are :

A: 1
B: 01
C: 00

and the encoded file looks like this: 11111010   10100000

notice that I don't need the last 3 bits which are 000. How do I know that I don't need these bits while Decoding ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't know. You need a way to terminate the bit stream, since it is stored in bytes. Either you need to provide the number of bits in the bit stream or the number of symbols to decode from the bit stream before the bit stream, or you need to add an end-of-stream symbol, which when encountered ends the decoding.